# Lines are disorted when using \cmidrule in booktab table

Tags: tables, formatting

I would be really glad if someone could help me out.

Im using the following code to generate a table:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccl}
    \toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\BART<BASE>$}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\SIMPLE<1L>$}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\SIMPLE<3L>$}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\SIMPLE<6L>$}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\SIMPLE<1L>$}\\
 \midline{2-3}\midline{4-5}\midline{6-7}\midline{8-9}\midline{10-11}
 & $\bpe$& $\wordwise$& $\bpe$& $\wordwise$& $\bpe$& $\wordwise$& $\bpe$& $\wordwise$& $\bpe$& $\wordwise$\\
 \midrule
         $\mathbf{Acc}$&  99.1\%&  98.1\%&  73.6\%&  56.0\%&  92.4\%&  87.2\%&  94.4\%&  89.7\%&  99.6\%& 99.7\%\\
         $\mathbf{Acc}_{BR}$&  90.5\%&  90.1\%&  33.7\%&  8.8\%&  81.7\%&  90.3\%&  78.1\%&  89.8\%&  95.3\%& 97.6\%\\
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Scores averaged over all grammars}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

I defined the command \midline in my document as

```
\newcommand\midline[1]{\cmidrule(lr){#1}}
```

But im ending up with stair-like clines.

[image]

I just want them to be next to eachother...

Comment: cmidrule looks ahead for a following cmidrule so they can be merged in to the same line, your macro hides that

Comment: Didn't know that. Thank you, it worked without the macro.

Comment: So yeah @David Carlisle noted rightfully that the merging of cmidrules doesn't work with macros.

Comment: You shouldn't be applying any right-hand trimming to the final `\cmidrule` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to not "entombing" the `\cmidrule` directives, you also should not right-trim the final `\cmidrule` line. I.e., replace `\cmidrule(lr){10-11}` with `\cmidrule(l){10-11}`. And, I think you should set up the 11 columns as `l *{10}{c}` rather than as `*{10}c l`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\bpe{\mathcal{T}^{\mathit{bpe}}}        % ?
\newcommand\wordwise{\mathcal{T}^{\mathit{words}}} % ?

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} l *{10}{c} @{}}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathrm{BART}_{\mathrm{BASE}}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathrm{SIMPLE}_{\mathrm{1L}}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathrm{SIMPLE}_{\mathrm{3L}}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathrm{SIMPLE}_{\mathrm{6L}}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\mathrm{SIMPLE}_{\mathrm{1L}}}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
  \cmidrule(l){10-11}
  & \bpe& \wordwise & \bpe& \wordwise
  & \bpe& \wordwise & \bpe& \wordwise
  & \bpe& \wordwise\\
\midrule
\mathbf{Acc}
   &  99.1\%&  98.1\%&  73.6\%&  56.0\%&  92.4\%&  87.2\%&  94.4\%&  89.7\%&  99.6\%& 99.7\%\\
\mathbf{Acc}_{\mathrm{BR}}
   &  90.5\%&  90.1\%&  33.7\%&  8.8\%&  81.7\%&  90.3\%&  78.1\%&  89.8\%&  95.3\%& 97.6\%\\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\caption{Scores averaged over all grammars}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to write your table is to use `tabularray`  \package with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx` which load packages of the same name:

```
\documentclass{article} % used document class is unknown
\usepackage{geometry}   % your document layout is unknown

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
% column headers symbols
\newcommand\Tbpe{\mathcal{T}^{\mathit{bpe}}} 
\newcommand\Tword{\mathcal{T}^{\mathit{words}}}
\newcommand\SIMPLE[1]{\mathrm{SIMPLE}_{\mathrm{#1L}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} Q[l, mode=math] *{10}{X[c, si={table-format=2.1}]} @{}},
             cell{1}{even[2]} = {c=2}{},
             cell{3-Z}{2-Z}   = {appto={\,\%}},
             row{1,2} = {guard, mode=math},  
             }
    \toprule
    & \mathrm{BART}_{\mathrm{BASE}}   &
    & \SIMPLE{1}        &
    & \SIMPLE{3}        &
    & \SIMPLE{6}        &
    & \SIMPLE{1}        &           \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-3}  \cmidrule[lr]{4-5}  \cmidrule[lr]{6-7} 
    \cmidrule[lr]{8-9}  \cmidrule[l]{10-11}
    & \Tbpe &\Tword & \Tbpe &\Tword & \Tbpe &\Tword & \Tbpe &\Tword & \Tbpe & \Tword    \\
    \midrule
\mathbf{Acc}
   & 99.1   & 98.1  & 73.6  & 56.0  & 92.4  & 87.2  & 94.4  & 89.7  & 99.6  & 99.7      \\
\mathbf{Acc}_{\mathrm{BR}}
   & 90.5   & 90.1  & 33.7  & 8.8   & 81.7  & 90.3  & 78.1  & 89.8  & 95.3  & 97.6      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Scores averaged over all grammars}
\label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]